# Paginated, sortable, collapsible datarows (tables) in mobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile, pagination, tablesorter

I want to implement the Demo shown at http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html in a mobile application. I want each row in the Demo to be collapsible/expandable. What is the best way to achieve it? To my knowledge tables don't work well in mobile applications. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

== EDIT ==

This is almost all I want

http://stokkers.mobi/jqm/tableview/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this will do in a mobile application, but check out [this demo](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm). No need to download that mod as it was added to [tablesorter 2.0.5](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

The demo shows how to use an undocumented option named `cssChildRow` which contains the class name `expand-child`. This class name is added to a table row `tr` to attach it to the row before it (example code from that demo):

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="collapsible"></td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="collapsible_alt"><a href="javascript:alert('Order # SO71774')">SO71774</a></td>
    <td>Good Toys</td>
    <td>PO348186287</td>
    <td>Jul 20, 2007</td>
    <td>$972.78</td>
</tr>
<tr class="expand-child">
    <td colspan="4">
        <div class="bold">Shipping Address</div>
        <div>
            99700 Bell Road<br /> Auburn, California 95603
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The code needed to make the rows collapsible in in this file: [jquery.tablesorter.collapsible.js](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.collapsible.js)

Comment: That is so cool :) I will wait for few more days just to see if anyone else has a better solution. This is almost perfect, but needs some tweaking for mobile screens/browsers. Thanks a ton for sharing it.